# How to create a custom sign-in page using windows authentication Mode

Tags: login

I'm trying to create a sign in page in Sharepoint. The page should offer the same functionality as the popup which is the sharepoint default interface for signing in.
But the client doesn't like it...
So what I need to know is how to do that.
Should I create a custom page?
How do I link this page so that every time this login page will appear when needed?

This question might sound stupid, but please guide me in this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here You have an example: http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2011/06/23/sharepoint-2010-custom-login-page/

Comment: While this post may answer the question, we prefer more details such as "why". Please edit your post with additional details. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

zavaz has given perfect answer.

For better understanding, you can also refer

http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1093

Comment: Thank you, but i don't understand why I don't see the fourth step.. I don't see the Custom Sign in page Url ..